# postfix: view sent emails

Tags: email, postfix-mta

Considering I have postfix setup on my server, How do I view emails that were sent to me?

Comment: Belongs on http://www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 5):

To clarify the question: You mean "How do I view the mails RECEIVED by Postfix?".

Posfix delivers mails to either mbox or Maildir storage (or others; if explicitly configured to use other storage engines like a database). So Postfix is only a program to receive and store messages (for inbound mail).

So you need a program that now reads mbox or Maildir storage to present the mail in there. This is *not* part of Postfix. This is done by a POP3 or IMAP server which allows you to access the storage via the POP3 or IMAP protocol. The server side of the protocol is done by software like Dovecot, Cyrus, Courier or UW IMAP. The client side of the protocol is handled by Mozilla Thunderbird, Outlook, The Bat or any other mail client.

If your question was "How do I see the mails SENT by Postfix?". The answer is very easy and short: You can't. (unless you trick a lot)